# Query Orc file on s3n is crazy slow

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, orc

As long as i query my ORC files on hdfs everything is nice and very fast - but when i want to query the data while it is stored on S3 it is crazy slow and the queries are not able to finish.

I am using Hive 0.12 
my create statement looks like this

```
CREATE external TABLE externalORCFiles (... , ... , ...)
STORED AS ORC 
location 's3n://...';
```

this seems to me like there was the same issue with ORC + Presto + S3 ([see here](https://github.com/facebook/presto/pull/2675) )but i could not find something similar for Hive

Comment: Any update on it? I`m facing the same issues on Hive 1.1

Comment: Anyone tried it with Presto on Amazon EMR??

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a very good storage space when it comes to cold storage. However is doesn't really fit the HDFS space. The S3 data moves at about 50Mbps (could be more or less, but much slower than HDFS). It is a choice for you to pick between speed & cost.

Comment: Hey imakarsh, thanks for responding.
It's okay that the read speed is not as fast as from HDFS but it is really insane slow ... it took a 16 node cluster 2hrs to perform the query on plain text files and the same cluster on ORC files completed about 5% of the job after that time...

I think the problem is, that the S3n - native Filesystem. For some reasons the performance of the Hive ORC filereader seems to be pretty pretty bad